# Python: why "breaking while loop if no input" do not pass testcase

Tags: python, python-3.x, testcase

Here two same codes in C++ and Python: function must be done repeatedly until no input. C++ code passes, but Python code do not pass testcases. what is problem on python code? thanks

python code:

```
def func(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        s=(n+1)//2
        return s*s + func(n//2)

while True:
    n=input()
    if n=='':
        break
    else:
        print(func(int(n)))
```

c++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long fun(long long n){
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    long long s=(n+1)/2;
    return s*s+fun(n/2);
}
int main(){
    long long n;
    while(cin>>n)
    cout<<fun(n)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Explain what "passing the test case" means for you. Is the criteria to "pass" the TC simply exiting the loop?

Comment: Why do you use `//2` in python code?

Comment: @aliasm2k: To… do integer division by two?

Comment: I thought `/2` should work. Was wondering why `//2` is essential. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Is your input on multiple lines? `cin >> n` will read a word, and `input()` will read a line.

Comment: @aliasm2k Its a python 3 thing. Now, integer division with '/' produces a float and '//' produces an int.

Comment: Ooh. Ok. I am not familiar with new features introduced in Python 3.

Comment: Cannot duplicate. Code produces data on positive numbers, exits on blank entry and raises exceptions on other input. Unless you tell us what case isn't valid, I vote this question should be closed.

Comment: @aliasm2k - re. "new features" - Python 3 was released in December 2008... btw, there is a summary of new features here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python

Comment: @ximic - be useful if you could paste your python "testcases" for further clarification about your question.

Comment: I am solving questions on website 'e-olymp.com', and I cannot see the test cases. As I understand the problem is on breaking the loop, while I made only 3 calls for function one test is passed (it mean one of the tests contains only three inputs)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert what you have to a [sentinel loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

```
def func(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        s=(n+1)//2
        return s*s + func(n//2)
val = input()
## ^^^^ ^^ This can be anything not ''
while val!='':
      print(func(int(val)))
      val=input()
```

Comment: Minor tweak for personal taste, but it doesn't change functionality or answer the question.

Comment: '“breaking while loop if no input” do not pass test case'.  I believe it does